# Erro ao publicar app no Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Estou tentando postar o Apk, mas aprece essa mensagem de erro

```
    O envio falhou
Você fez o upload de um APK depurável. Por razões de segurança, desative a depuração antes de publicá-lo no Google Play. Saiba mais sobre APKs depuráveis..
Use um nome de pacote diferente. "com.example" é restrito.
```

Comment: Você tem que compilar no modo release o seu app, e mudar o nome do pacote também se comecar com com.example, também recomendo a utilizar o proguard no seu app. Não sei se é obrigatorio criar outro certificado também para assinar seu app.

Comment: brother, tentei renomear, mas da erro em tudo, sabe uma forma como de como posso mudar o nome do pacote.

Comment: Não precisa renomear o pacote, é só gerar um apk assinado, em modo release, aonde vc gera uma key pra ele, você não pode subir um app em debug pra playstore, da uma lida nesse link: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/preparing.html

Comment: Insira seu manifest na pergunta por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Google Play não aceita uma versão de depuração do seu arquivo `.apk` . Você só pode enviar um `.apk` compilado como versão de lançamento. Além disso, ele deve ser assinado com a chave de desenvolvedor Android. 
Certifique-se de distribuir um arquivo `.apk` que é a sua versão assinadas, conforme descrito aqui na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasecompile) do Android:

Por gerar sua chave de depuração que seria algo como:

```
$keytool -list -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

- Keystore name: "debug.keystore"
- Keystore password: "android"
- Key alias: "androiddebugkey"
- Key password: "android"
- CN: "CN=Android Debug,O=Android,C=US"

Por gerar sua chave de release seria alterado para:

```
$keytool -list -v -keystore "c:\minhachave.keystore" -alias minhachave -storepass android
```